# Is it ok to wrap my web site in Flutter web view

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I have a website and now I need to have mobile app in order to be able to send push notifications to my users and provide limited scope of functionalities of my web application.

Since this will be simplified version of my website’s functionality, my plan is to first check if my web is responsive and looks OK on mobile browsers, and modify it if needed.

Then I plan to create simple mobile app in Flutter with webview component that will just load my website inside app.

The motive is to have one simple code base for both platforms That’s easy to maintain.

Will Flutter’s webview be suitable for this kind of use-case?

Other options are to use PWA and browser push/notification messages, or to learn React Native, Xamarin or something similar. My preference is the first aproach, but only if it looks suitable for my use-case.

Comment: Flutter uses native web toolkits so it should be like using the native browser but with a bit of a different implementation. Using React or Xamarin will probably give you the same experience as flutter seeing that they're also cross platform solutions just with a different implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Based on the readings I’ve done, Flutter’s webview looks promising. Since this seems Like a rather simple app to develop, I guess the only thing That’s left for me is to create it and test if everything renders as expected.

Comment: There is a risk that Apple will reject you app under [clause 4.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality). Also PWA cannot receive push notifications on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 this is really helpful comment, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to wrap a PWA. When it feels like a native app, the app will not get rejected by Apple. I've done it multiple times!

I even wrote a [Flutter PWA Wrapper](https://github.com/bettysteger/flutter_pwa_wrapper) to enable native Push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can wrap app using [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/), open source project founded by Microsoft